# Логи в кастомной службе Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar, service

Есть jar файл и запускался он через `nohup java -jar /path/app.jar > /path/out.log 2>&1`, где успешно все логи сохранялись в отдельный файл

Но сама идея не очень удобна и я создал службу, но все никак не могу получить файл с логами, а смотреть syslog или journalctl не вариант.

Как мне получить логи в отдельный файл?

```
app.service
[Unit]
Description = app
After=network.target
After=postgres.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/path/
ExecStart=nohup java -jar /path/app.jar > /path/out.log 2>&1

SuccessExitStatus=143
TimoutStopSec=10
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Не понятна проблема. В файл ничего не пишется?

Comment: @TotalPusher он даже не создается

Comment: Оператор `>` является оператором шелла (sh или bash), но в опции ExecStart никакой шелл не используется и символ `>` становится самым обычным ничего не делающим аргументом, который передаётся в вашу программу как есть. Если вы хотите использовать штуки специфичные для шелла, то заверните ваш ExecStart в шелл: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'nohup java ...'`

Comment: Правда, в качестве побочных эффектов могут возникнуть непонятки с остановкой службы (возможно, понадобится поиграться с опцией `KillMode`), а ещё непонятно зачем в systemd-службе вообще использовать nohup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), логи можно перенаправить при помощи опций `StandardOutput` и `StandardError` в секции `[Service]`

Например:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/path/
ExecStart=nohup java -jar /path/app.jar
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/app.stdout.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/app.stderr.log
```

Comment: все отлично работает, но есть нюанс, как можно удалить предыдущий лог при рестарте сервиса?

Comment: А для этого есть logrotate.